# В битриксе не изменяется свойство заказа

Tags: php, битрикс

В Битрикс при создании заказа пытаюсь изменить ему пользовательское свойство `телефон` (нужно изменить формат), но оно не меняется, хотя остальные поля изменяются.

Обработчик

```
$eventManager = \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleOrderBeforeSaved', 'orderModify');

function orderModify($event)
{
    /** @var \Bitrix\Sale\Order $order */
    $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
    $propertyCollections = $order->getPropertyCollection();

    /** @var Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue $propertyCollection */
    foreach ($propertyCollections as $propertyCollection) {

        if ($propertyCollection->getField('CODE') == 'PHONE') {
            $propertyCollection->setValue(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $propertyCollection->getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поле телефон множественное или нет?

Comment: Поле не множественное